# MVC Model DisplayFormat for Array type attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I was wondering if I have a model class like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

In my View I use DisplayFor, so it does show all emails, but just as one string.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emails)
```

john@gmail.comjohn@hotmail.comjohn@microsoft.com

Is there some kind of DisplayFormat attribute that I can apply to Emails property,
so that it would display all emails for a single contact, separated by a comma, like this:

**john@gmail.com, john@hotmail.com, john@microsoft.com**

Dont really want to use foreach(var email in Model.Email) in my view for this simple operation.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding the appropriate programming language tag. In PHP i would use something like implode(Emails, ', '), i gues this language has a similar feature

Comment: You could create an editor template. Check this out: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Thanks Andre, I would nee the editor too :)

Answer (score 3):

How about adding another string property to the ViewModel to represent a comma seperated version of the string array and use that in the view

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
    public string EmailsCommaSeperated 
    { 
      get
      {
        return String.Join(",",Emails);
      }
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailsCommaSeperated)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => String.Join(", ", item.Emails))` work as well?

Comment: @AndreCalil: It is same thing. I want to keep it to the POCO(ViewModel) so that the View looks **clean and readable** without so many function calls.

Comment: I see. As this class is a *model*, and not a simple *view model*, I'd prefer not to add view logic to it. However, it's a minor decision. +1 for the straightforward suggestion

Comment: @AndreCalil: I edited the answer to include the ViewModel word.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom helper.

This video tutorial will help you:
http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-views&mode=live&clip=6&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro